# I cannot use bootstrap for wordpress theme header links

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm coding a Wordpress theme, and I'm using Bootstrap for doing that. But I have a problem that I cannot give the Bootstrap classes to the links and list items surrounding the links. What should I do? Here's a piece of my code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

  <title><?php echo bloginfo('name') . " - " . the_title();?></title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <?php wp_head();?>

</head>
<body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md bg-light navbar-light">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><?php echo bloginfo('name');?></a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapsibleNavbar">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="collapsibleNavbar">
  <?php
    wp_nav_menu(
      array(
        'theme_location' => 'top_menu',
        'menu_class' => 'navbar-nav',
        'container' => 'ul',
      )
    );
  ?>
  </div>
</nav>
</body>
</html>
```

I appreciate any help. Thanks

Comment: How have you included the bootstrap css files?

Comment: First I downloaded Bootstrap files and then linked my theme to them using functions.php.

Comment: Can you show us the code please? There is obviously something not working in how they are included

Comment: I edited the code above. Check it again please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You sure can add custom classes to your list and list items

WordPress allows you to define a custom menu walker.

See: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/248369/how-to-create-this-custom-menu-walker

Or

https://www.ibenic.com/how-to-create-wordpress-custom-menu-walker-nav-menu-class/